Building SAMBA AD DC container with Docker and Kubernetes gives wrong content to volumes
I am building a container for Kubernetes that runs a SAMBA Active Directory Domain Controller.
I am doing the job through Ansible and the container is being deployed in a Kubernetes cluster (K3S).
Docker is using the following files as part of its build:
etc/krb5.conf
etc/bind/rndc.key
etc/bind/named.conf.local
etc/bind/db.0
etc/bind/db.255
etc/bind/db.empty
etc/bind/named.conf.options
etc/bind/db.local
etc/bind/named.conf
etc/bind/db.127
etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones
etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/eap
etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/realm
etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/ntlm_auth
etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/mschap
etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf
etc/freeradius/3.0/proxy.conf
etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/default
etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/inner-tunnel
boot/init.sh
boot/kdb5_util_create.expect
Dockerfile

The idea is that for all files the path is the same inside the container, but / as a prefix.
However I came across something strange when inspecting the running container that was compiled as a result.

The content of /etc/samba, /etc/bind and /etc/freeradius is definitely not supposed to be the same!
The content of my Dockerfile is as follows:
FROM ubuntu:noble

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Avoid ERROR: invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

VOLUME ["/var/lib/samba", "/etc/samba", "/etc/bind", "/etc/freeradius", "/SambaVolume"]

# Setup ssh and install supervisord
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server supervisor ntp mc
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
RUN sed -ri 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin Yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Add SAMBA VolumeShare location
RUN mkdir -p /SambaVolume

# Install bind9 dns server
RUN apt-get install -y bind9 dnsutils
# Copy tweaked DNS setttings (instead of ADD, due to we want to overwrite any existing files)
COPY etc/bind/* /etc/bind/

# Install samba and dependencies to make it an Active Directory Domain Controller
RUN apt-get install -y samba smbclient winbind libpam-winbind libnss-winbind krb5-kdc libpam-krb5

# Install Freeradius so validate VPN users against samba
RUN apt-get install -y freeradius

# Copy Freeradius customised files
COPY etc/freeradius/ /etc/freeradius/

# Copy customized kerberos configuration file
COPY etc/krb5.conf /etc/

# Install utilities needed for setup
RUN apt-get install -y expect pwgen
ADD boot/kdb5_util_create.expect /root/kdb5_util_create.expect

# Install rsyslog to get better logging of ie. bind9
RUN apt-get install -y rsyslog

# Create run directory for bind9
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/named
RUN chown -R bind:bind /var/run/named

# Add supervisord and init
ADD etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
ADD boot/init.sh /root/init.sh
RUN chmod 755 /root/init.sh
EXPOSE 53/tcp 53/udp 80/tcp 80/udp 88/tcp 88/udp 135/tcp 135/udp 137/tcp 137/udp 
EXPOSE 138/tcp 138/udp 389/tcp 389/udp 443/tcp 443/udp 445/tcp 445/udp 464/tcp 464/udp 
EXPOSE 636/tcp 636/udp 3268/tcp 3268/udp 3269/tcp 3269/udp 9389/tcp 9389/udp
EXPOSE 123/udp 22/tcp 22/udp
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/init.sh"]
CMD ["app:start"]

And the compiled container is being stored in a local register using the following commands:
  docker build -t samba:latest samba/
  docker tag samba:latest registry.example.com:5000/samba:latest
  docker push registry.example.com:5000/samba:latest  

It is being deployed through Ansible with the following task:
- name: Create SAMBA Deployment
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: StatefulSet
      metadata:
        name: samba
        namespace: samba-system
        labels:
          app: samba
      spec:
        replicas: 1
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            app: samba
        template:
          metadata:
            labels:
              app: samba
          spec:
            volumes:
              - name: samba-config
                persistentVolumeClaim:
                  claimName: samba-config-vol

            containers:
              - name: samba
                image: registry.example.com:5000/samba:latest
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 123
                    protocol: UDP

#           ### SKIPPING ###

                 - containerPort: 9389
                    protocol: UDP
                  - containerPort: 9389
                    protocol: TCP

                volumeMounts:
                  - name: samba-config
                    mountPath: /etc/samba
                  - name: samba-config
                    mountPath: /etc/bind
                  - name: samba-config
                    mountPath: /etc/freeradius
                  - name: samba-config
                    mountPath: /var/lib/samba

                envFrom:
                  - configMapRef:
                      name: samba-environment-map

                securityContext:
                  priviledged: true
                  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
                  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false

                  capabilities:
                    add:
                      - ALL

I am wondering why the content of the folders /etc/bind, /etc/samba and /etc/freeradius is the same.
I thought I read somewhere that you could use the same persistentVolumeClaim for all folders?

This happens because you mount single volume named samba-config onto multiple volumeMounts. Think about this as mounting the same block device onto different mount points under Linux (in ro mode of course) - you'll get the same contents in all of these directories..

But volumeMounts has a property called subPath that was supposed keep track of different subfolders inside the PVC. The documentation says something multiple containers can share the same volume and each pod is distinguished by a unique subfolder inside PVC. I was hoping different folders defined on the same pod could do the same? The reason why I am doing it is because Freeradius needs to run on same host as Samba in order to authenticate users via Radius against SAMBA user management. And Bind also needs to run on the same as SAMBA as it provides DNS backend for SAMBA.

Please read this detailed discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399714/what-is-the-difference-between-subpath-and-mountpath-in-kubernetes) on StackOverflow that will clarify how both multiple volumeMounts and subPath play together and what Kubernetes does to make it work.

Yes I have read it. And subPath is definitely the way to go, although I had to re-read a few times to find out what is going on. Basically you can set subPath to have any value as long as it is unique. It is just a subfolder inside the volumeMount. And whatever is inside the folder gets mounted at the path specified in mountPath. After rebuilding my image and delete and recreated my PVC a few times I can at least get SAMBA and Freeradius to mount the right way. The bind folder is for some reason still empty, so I have to think a bit about what is going on.
